# MVC3 Controller returning JsonFile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am having a problem with a json result.  When calling from the jquery it is returning a file to be saved instead of executing the success function. The get jquery request occurs in the document.ready function.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public ActionResult Locations()
    {
        LocationsModel lm = new LocationsModel();
        return Json(lm.getPins(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
public JsonResult Locations()
    {
        LocationsModel lm = new LocationsModel();
        return Json(lm.getPins(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The jquery is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: this.href,
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) { getPins_success(msg); },
        error: OnError
    });
```

Thanks,
Chris

Edit:

Never mind it was a duh. Once I moved the json request to another action in the controller and loaded the view it all worked out. Now I am having parsing problems but that is another issue all together.

Comment: `AllowGet` and `type: "POST"` ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead.

For you it would be:

```
$.getJSON(this.href, function (msg) { getPins_success(msg); });
```

This will let you parse the return data as json.